# Multiple plotting from dataframe using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to improve my visualizations on Python. Assume I have this data:

```
data = {'animal':['cat', 'tiger', 'leopard', 'dog'], 'family':['mustelids ','felidae','felidae', 'canidae'], 'family_pct':[6.06,33.33,9.09,12.12]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a barplot as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(x = 'family', y = 'family_pct', hue='animal', data = df)
```

However, I would like each "family" to be plotted separately (one plot for mustelids, one for felidae, and one for canidae) and not on the same plot. I effectively would like to loop the graph over every value of the family column. However, I am not sure how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out sns' [FacetGrid](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use catplot() to combine a barplot() and a FacetGrid. This allows grouping within additional categorical variables. Using catplot() is safer than using FacetGrid directly, as it ensures synchronization of variable order across facets:

```
sns.catplot(x = 'family', y = 'family_pct', hue='animal', col='family', data = df, kind='bar', height=4, aspect=.7)
```

See more details [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).